# How do I run a Python script from command line in a WPF application

Tags: c#, python, wpf

I am trying to run a Python script from cmd line in a WPF application. I have this code which opens cmd line to the correct directory:

```
string cmd = @"webplus_builder.py";
             Process p = new Process();
             p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
             p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp\WebBuilder";
             p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", cmd, "WAF", _CountryCode);

             p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
             p.Start();
```

[image]

I now want to run `webplus_builder.py` from that directory like so:

[image]

How do I achieve this? Is it a case of just adding arguments to my `Process` as I've attempted to do?

Comment: You'd have to execute something like `cmd.exe /c python.exe ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute python scripts directly, it's `python` itself that has to be run: Use the name of your script as the first parameter to it, the following parameters are passed to your script.

*(Windows handles a double click on py-files by "opening them with" python - exactly as described).*

Read the official docs for details:

- [1. Command line and environment — Python 2.7.9 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)
- [1. Command line and environment — Python 3.3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html)